# Number of the ways to place six X's in a specific arrangement of squares.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question says:
Six X's have to be placed in the squares of figure below in such a way that each row contains atleast one X. In how many ways can this be done?
The figure:

[image]

My approach:
Let's first ensure that each row has atleast one X. So

Number of ways to place one X in top row: ${2 \choose 1} = 2$

Number of ways to place one X in middle row: ${4 \choose 1} = 4$

Number of ways to place one X in bottom row: ${2 \choose 1} = 2$

Number of ways I can redistribute remaining 3 X's in 5 remaining boxes ${5 \choose 3} = 10$

Thus total number of ways are: $2 \cdot4\cdot2\cdot10 = 160 $

But this answer has some flaw which I am unable to get. Kindly tell what exact mistake is there in my approach?

Comment: You are over counting.  There's no way to distinguish between, say, the first $X$ you put in the top row and the second one that gets thrown there when you distribute the extra $3$, thus you count every arrangement with two $X's$ on top at least twice.

Comment: Seems easier to work off the complement.  Describe all the ways to place five $X's$ that fail the test.  Or just describe all the good patterns directly.  The numbers are so small here that neither method is difficult.

Comment: @lulu so basically I am assuming the X's to be distinct objects while they are actually the identical object right?

Comment: That doesn't matter.  If you put $X_1,X_3$ in the top row, you would still count it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Total ways to select 6 places out of $8$ places $\binom{8}{6}=\binom{8}{2}=28$.

Number of ways to select 6 places so that first row is empty: $1$ (since we have only 6 places remaining.)

Number of ways to select 6 places so that second row is empty: $0$ (since we have to select 6 from remaining 4 places which is not possible.)

Number of ways to select 6 places so that third row is empty: $1$

Hence the answer is $28-(1+0+1)=26$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).